# Взаимодействия с date type c#

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, datetime, access

Для примера :
Существует база данных, сделанная на ms access, в ней базируется 4 таблицы :

1. Таблица виды заказов,
2. Таблица текущих заказов,
3. Таблица просроченные заказы,
4. Таблица полученные заказы.

Между этими таблицами определена связь. Реализовано добавление, удаление и редактирование данных, вывод таблиц в текстовый редактор => классика жанра.

Но была попытка усложнить себе жизнь и создать условие для передачи данных из 2-ой таблицы  в 3 или 4, которое влияет на выбор таблицы.
Все бы ничего, но условие проверяет датированное поле "Время Заказа" во 2-ой таблице, используя при этом календарный отчёт (игнорируется шкала времени). Если проходит промежуток времени (например неделя) и заказ не получает индикатор "выполнено", то он автоматически перемещается в таблицу "Просроченные заказы". В реализации индикатора не вижу большой проблемы, но уже сломал мозг, пытаясь сделать самостоятельно или найти прецеденты такого формата (условие проверки поля дата). Оценю любую помощь, даже совет. При необходимости могу скинуть свой бред. [image: Сама база данных]

Comment: Приведите определения таблиц и связей. Лучше один раз увидеть код, чем читать описание словами.

Comment: @A K , полностью солидарен, но я только с поста ушел, так что - прошу прощения.

Comment: Гм. Скажите, а вы в курсе, что есть более простой способ хранить ваши данные? Классика жанра: все заказы хранятся в одной таблице Orders, в котором есть поле int Status, никакие данные не нужно никуда переливать постоянно, всё хранится в одном месте. База данных ещё вам спасибо скажет - когда вы задумаетесь о быстродействии и начнёте думать в терминах статистики индексов, дефрагментации индексов, планах выполнения запроса и т.п. вещах. Например, OverdueOrders - это все Orders в статуce 1 и Order.CreateDate + 7 days < DateTime.Now