# Перемещение ряда из одной таблицы в другую с условием

Tags: c#, база-данных, access, datagrid, таблицы

Столкнулся с необходимостью перемещения (наследование) данных (ряда) из одной таблицы в другую с **условием** (в данном случае их два)
Первое при вводе определенного значения, второе при сравнении двух дат (записанная в колонке и настоящая дата). Код скину чуть позже из-за отсутствия доступа к пк. А форматирование кода на телефоне работает не совсем некорректно.

Comment: Видимо, этот тот же вопрос, но вы так и не ответили, действительно ли надо хранить данные таким неудобным способом - [мой комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1285529/%d0%92%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-date-type-c#comment2266663_1285529) в силе. "Доктор, когда я так делаю - у меня что-то хрустит и не получается. А вы так не делайте!" И наверное нехорошо обсуждать вопрос без кода. Давайте его закроем, а когда вы будете готовы - откроем.

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Взаимодействия с date type c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1285529/%d0%92%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-date-type-c) ?

Comment: `Код скину чуть позже из-за отсутствия доступа к пк` так и задавайте вопрос чуть позже, когда уже будет доступ ко всему необходимому.

Comment: @AK, скорей всего забыл.  "мой комментарий" - для меня это была самая удобная конструкция для передачи данных, то есть полная субъективность. Ведь я хотел понять, как реализовывать передачу (копирование) данных из одной таблицы в другую с условием, но т.к. больше туториалов, да и в принципе source project содержат, либо одну таблицу, либо их многотабличность реализуется куда более простыми способами, но не подходящими, ведь я ограничен в рамках возможностей winform. Была бы моя воля, то я подтянул знание wpf или вообще использовал бы React.

Comment: @AK, К слову, мне стоит создать новую тему + вложить туда свой код и гипотетические условия обработки рядов + их дальнейшую передачу? Для меня форум - диковинка.

Comment: Вы уже две создали. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Главное - укажите все необходимое для ответа на вопрос, пока что вы заново на одни и те же вопросы не можете ответить. Вот только что вас второй раз спросили, почему вам так не подходит, как по классике - БЕЗ копирования данных между таблицами и снова тишина. Какие статьи и тьюториалы читали, что не подходит, чем именно -- всё это нужно указывать в вопросе.